# How to return an array using awk through Bash script from a remote server

Tags: linux, bash, awk, remote-access, remote-server

**SCENARIO**

A file `users.yml` contains several usernames and passwords. Some of the usernames and passwords are repeating. For instance...

```
xxxxx
username: abc
password: abcpwd
xxxxx
xxxxx
username: adam
password: adampwd
xxxxx
xxxxx
username: adam
password: adampwd
xxxxx
```

A script file `script.sh` is trying to get all the line numbers where usernames from the `users.yml` matches the criteria.

```
username='adam'
filepath='/etc/myServer/users.yml'

#Gets the line number for the username
userNameLineNumbers=`awk -v line='^.*username: '$username'' '$0~line {print NR}' $filepath`

echo "username line number: "$userNameLineNumbers  #output: username line number: 6 10
```

This script is working fine if I run the script on the same machine where the `users.yml` is resided. However, the problem is...

**PROBLEM**

The script does not work if I keep the script on another server and try to get the line numbers from the file remotely.

I tried several ways to get the line numbers using `ssh` but unable to do it. I am not an expert on bash scripting, but still tried the following command in different ways and each time it gives some weird results instead of giving me line numbers from the file.

```
script="sudo awk -v line='^.*username: '$username'' '$0~line {print NR}' $filepath"
userNameLineNumbers=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -tty -i "$PEM_FILE" "user@remotehost.xyz" $script )
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

Looking for a solution to get the line numbers as an array from a file on a remote server where `awk` matches the criteria.

Comment: Maybe try using `ssh -t` ...

Comment: @l'L'l, nope `ssh -t` didn't help either

Comment: Re: "didn't help"... what does it do?

Comment: ..Nothing, doesn't even advance to the next line, which is an echo.. command.

Comment: No shell or awk function can `return an array` and your script does nothing related to arrays so not sure what you're trying to tell us with that part of your question.

Comment: @EdMorton I didn't include the whole script as part of my question. The real script does things based on the array I received. For this question, I think it is enough to print (echo) the result (user name lines) I receive.

Comment: The more you can focus your question on the thing you really are asking for help with the better we'll be able to help you. You clearly aren't asking for help with anything related to "returning an array" so don't talk about that as it just obfuscates your real needs. Just state what you are actually asking for help with **in this question**.

Answer (score 0):

Two changes I can think of:

1. use `eval` for running the command inside `$script` variable
2. Escape `$` in `$0`. Otherwise it gets expanded to the value of `$0`, which gives the command used to invoke current shell (eg. `-bash`)

`script="sudo awk -v line='^.*username: '$username'' '\$0~line {print NR}' $filepath"
userNameLineNumbers=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -tty -i "$PEM_FILE" "user@remotehost.xyz" eval $script )`

Comment: thanks for the answer. but it doesn't work. I added another line, `echo "username line number: "$userNameLineNumbers ` that doesn't print anything, not even 'username line number: ' and the script fails already on the ssh line.